# grpc readable/ascii (Devs are afraid of binary)

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

Up to now I only read about grpc and [protocol-buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers).

I talked to some team mates. They never heard of it before. They are afraid of the binary data transfer.

They fear that it is hard to debug.

I can understand their feeling.

Is there a way to access grpc/protocol-buffers via a readable way (for debugging?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your direct question, yes you can the text format representation of protobuf called `TextFormat`.     It doesn't provide the same backwards compatibility guarantees as normal protobuf, but it is human readable and looks similar to JSON.

That said, being able to read the protobufs in binary form on the wire isn't commonly needed.  The binary form of Protos can be very easily decoded and printed out on each endpoint.  For example, the generated code contains methods to take a binary protobuf and print out the text representation.  Tools that interact with proto all use these text based representations of the binary data to inspect and debug data.

One other thing to consider: gRPC uses SSL to communicate, so you usually can't look at the traffic directly anyways.  You need a program to decrypt it, which is usually the point at which you decode the protos as well.

Lastly: Other text representations of data, namely JSON, are typically minified before being sent, and you can't directly read it anyways.  You would need to run it though a formatter, which is about the same level of effort as decoding a binary proto.